# Web server config - shttpd/Mongoose

Tags: c, http, mongoose-web-server

http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/
http://shttpd.sourceforge.net/shttpd.1.txt

Trying to configure the lightweight web server shttpd now called mongoose to execute CGI scripts in C.

Does it need a seperate CGI interpreter for C?

A download of shttpd on source forge had separate interpreter exe for perl and php cgi but not sure if that means I need one in C...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is not interpreted - you need to compile your CGI program before it can be run. And for any specific Mongoose questions, you may want to use the support group at http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-users/topics

Answer (score 3):

Actually, with tiny C compiler (http://bellard.org/tcc/) it is very possible to run .c files as scripts. Just add `#!/usr/local/bin/tcc -run` at the first line of your C source.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, your CGI executable is a binary executable.
If you're on UNIX, rename your CGI executable to have '.cgi' extension.
If you're on Windows, and CGI executable has '.exe' extension, specify server option "-cgi_ext exe"

Comment: thank you.  I had implemented this web server in C (cocoa, actually), very simply, and was angry it wasn't running the cgi's like it had when running by itself.  just adding .cgi is a small price to pay to make it just work.